# SQL query: How to show NULL when there is no retationship between two tables

Tags: sql, join, select, foreign-keys

I have two tables in my DB:

Table A:

- ID
- P1
- P2

Table B:

- ID
- P3
- A_ID which is a foreign key for Table A.ID

Assuming I have the following data in my tables:

```
+----+----+----+           +----+----+------+
| ID | P1 | P2 |           | ID | P3 | A_ID |
+----+----+----+           +----+----+------+
| 1  | aa | aa |           | B1 | aa |  1   |
+----+----+----+           +----+----+------+
| 2  | bb | bb |
+----+----+----+
```

As you can see only the 1st entity of table A has a relationship with an entity of table B, so I want to show (**SELECT**) something like this and set to 2nd entity of table A NULL values:

```
+----+----+----+----+
| P1 | P2 | P3 | ID |
+----+----+----+----+
| aa | aa | aa | B1 |
+----+----+----+----+
| bb | bb |null|null|
+----+----+----+----+
```

Which is the query I need to write in order to achieve that result?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: You need an *Outer Join*: `a LEFT join b`

Comment: @dnoeth I have tried it but probrably I am doing something wrong. May you show exactly how to do this ?

Comment: Show your existing Select. You probably got a condition in the wrong place. Rule of thumb: *conditions on the outer table (a) are added to WHERE, but conditions on the inner table (b) are added to ON*, e.g. `from a LEFT join b on a.col=b.col and b.col > 0 where a.col> 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship is not between individual rows but between tables.
A foreign key is the database way to enforce said relationship.

Having said that - you want a left join query:

```
SELECT A.P1, A.P2, B.P3, B.ID
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
    ON A.ID = B.A_ID
```

Comment: Glad to help :-)